# ES6 Interpolation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have one configuration file 
Abc.js

```
export const config = {
  name:'Name',
  rollNo: 'Roll Number'
}

export const name = {
  london  :'london',
  newYork :'newYork'
}

export const rollNo = {
  1:'one',
  2: 'two'
}
```

Then,I have one component where I am using this configuration file:

```
import * as configuration from 'Abc';

Object.keys(configuration.config).map(key,index)
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
    <td><Field name={`${key}`} id={`${key}`}
    options={configuration.${key}}
    />  
   </tr>
   </td>
)
```

I would like to interpolate key in options so that if key is name,I want to read `configuration.name` from `Abc.js`

Can anyone tell me way to interpolate this.

Comment: You don’t need interpolation here - just use `name={ key }`, `id={ key }` and `options={ configuration[key] }`

Comment: `JSX` **already** is _evaluating_ what's inside `{}` as javascript

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need to use string interpolation here:

```js
Object.keys(configuration.config).map((key, index) => (
  <tr key={ index }>
    <td>
      <Field name={ key } id={ key } options={ configuration[key] } />  
    </td>
  </tr>
));
```